# Trouble Creating and showing Users in Rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I keep getting a variety of error while trying to create and show errors in a simple Rails blog I'm trying to create.Let me know if you see anything obvious or if you need me to post more code as I've tried a number of things but to no avail. Thanks

The browser is giving me this error

Couldn't find User without an ID

in my "logged_in?" method which shows

```
def logged_in?
   @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
     session[:user_id] = user.id
     flash[:success] = "You are logged in"
     redirect_to root_path
    else
  render action: 'new'
    flash[:error] = "There was a problem logging in. Please check your email and password"
   end
  end
end


def index
 @users = User.all
end

def show
end


def new
 @user = User.new
end


def edit
end


def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
     session[:user_id] = @user.id
     flash[:notice] = "You have registered, please login"
     redirect_to login_path
  else
   render :new
  end
end



  def update
     respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
      else
       format.html { render action: 'edit' }
       format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
  end


def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to users_url }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
end

private

def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end


  def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Articles Controller

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

   http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show]

 def new
   @article = Article.new
 end

 def index
  @article = Article.all
 end

  def create  
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
     if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
     else
    render 'new'
     end
  end

 def edit
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   if @article.update(article_params)
     redirect_to @article
   else
  render 'edit'
  end
 end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

 def destroy
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   @article.destroy

   redirect_to articles_path
 end



 private

 def article_params
   params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :image)
 end
end
```

Application Helper

```
   module ApplicationHelper

 def logged_in?
   @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
 end
```

Comment: Do you have `create` actions defined twice in one controller or does it come from two different controllers?

Comment: Why would the `logged_in?` helper try to assign a value to `@current_user`? I think that is a bad logic, it should just return a boolean without modifying such a central instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that `session[:user_id]` is `nil`. Usually a method which sets current user is called `current_user`. The `logged_in?` is not a good name for a method setting an user instance,  because one would expect that a method ending with a question mark would return a `true` or `false`. And not an user instance.

Also, setting the current user is usually done with a `before_filter`. Additionally, you want to skip such [before filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter) for action where you're setting the current user (i.e the current_user doesn't exist yet)

Finally, I would rather fail gracefully, if user is not found. You can achieve this by changing your code to `User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])`

Comment: "Additionally, you want to skip such before filter for action where you're setting the current user (i.e the current_user doesn't exist yet)" can you explain what you mean with this? such before_filter is essential regardless IMHO.

Comment: Before you set up a session for given user you can expect the `user_id` will be nil. So if you want to limit the ability for non logged user, to view certain parts of your application, you definitely do not want to limit the access to the logging in functionality (i.e the `new` and`create` action in sessions). Because the user would never be able to authenticate himself, as he would be `halted` by the filter.

Comment: A filter doesn't necessarily have to change the flow of the application. It can just assign a variable and go on. That's why [the have been renamed to *_action instad of *_filter](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d62e04838f01f5589fa50b0baa480d60c815e2c).

Answer (score 1):

While  the user is not loggued, `session[:user_id]` is nil, and so `User.find(session[:user_id])` generates the error. The method should be like this:

```
def logged_in?
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id].present?
end
```

Comment: or simpler: `User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])`

Answer (score 0):

Why would the `logged_in?` helper method try to assign a value to `@current_user?` I think that is a bad logic, it should just return a boolean result without modifying such a central instance. This is a proper way to do that:

```
def logged_in?
  @current_user.nil? ? false : true
end
```

The responsibility of setting the `@current_user` falls to a method that you should place in `application_controller.rb` and make it a `before_action` so that it's executed before any controller action is triggered, that is:

```
# app/controllers/applicaton_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_action :authenticate_user

  # Your actions here
  ..
  ..
  #

  private
  def authenticate_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id].present?
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll try and change some things up here guys and see what works. I'm a definite newbie here and still learning so I appreciate any and all advice/criticisms one can give me. Will let you know in a bit how things go and check an answer. Thanks for all the replies.